# Invalid Password BitBucket in PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, bitbucket

When I use `git clone` with a Bitbucket account I get this error message:

> remote: **Invalid username or password**. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you hard set in your account profile.
>
> fatal: **Authentication failed** for 'https://andreraica@bitbucket.org/******.git/'

Everything is configured with all permissions OK.

The `git clone` command works on another machine, but I'm having problem with a new Windows 10 installation with Git Windows (Git GUI).

Comment: I realized that at the machine that works i used git bash for windows and ask me about the password in powershell prompt

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to cancel the 'Git windows credential pop up' and PowerShell is prompting for the password.

I used the same password used in 'Git windows credential pop up' and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Git support 6 different transfer protocols.

http - is for read only
https - require name and password for each server side operation (git pull, git push, fetch etc)

Switch to ssh keys instead and you will not have to use passwords

Comment: tks. I understand my friend, but in others machine works with https